# Php username filter / validate

Tags: php, security, pdo

I just wanted to ask if this is a secure way to let a user choose his username(user can use every digit):

```
if($_POST['username'] != "") {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
}
```

After this snippet I use PDO (prepared statement) to insert data in database.

You think this is secure enough or did I forget some important points?

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP Documentation - Filter flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php):

> FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW Strips characters that has a numerical value <32

This option is good for username validation, however, for preventing SQL injection attack, you should use parametrized prepared statement (using placeholders) for more information please refer to this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info and [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Because without using placeholders, even if you use prepared statement, userinput data will not be escaped by server.

Comment: is there any possibitity to put sanitize function in public_function, so the returned value can be 1 or 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
```

Maybe an idea to search for some info about SQL injections.

Comment: Yes it is safe enough.

Comment: In many cases, calling `mysqli_escape_string` after sanitizing a variable is more than enough. Also, try and use a prepared statement or PDO instead of passing a variable directly into a query string.

Comment: is there any possibitity to put sanitize function in public_function, so the returned value can be 1 or 0 ?